# At what point will questions get moved over from the main Stack Overflow site?

Tags: feature-request

There's a lot of good EE questions over there. Once the site goes to public beta, will those get moved over here? I have no idea how that works.

Comment: @RobertCartaino , I'm hoping you in particular can answer this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW I'd sincerely hope that existing EE questions on SO would be moved to here. There is no reason a visitor could not be redirected. I think I've seen that with some other questions. Click a link on the SO site to view the question and you are taken to, say, the Webmasters SE site. There is a note appended to the question saying it was migrated from the the other place.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's appropriate to move existing questions which have already been answered (SEO etc).

However, if someone has moderator privilege on SO (10k rep - I know none of us are even close) then they could potentially move most/all future questions here.

To @RobertCartaino et al - The reason I think this is a valid concern is that many EE questions on SO are actually getting closed as "off-topic" or "too localized", while they would be valid here. For example, [PHP errors encountered while trying to install/run ExpressionEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457430/getting-undefined-index-error-in-ip-to-nation-module-in-ee1-7-3).

Comment: CMIIW, but I think there is some precedent for migrating existing questions to other SE sites? Thought that happened when ServerFault started up anyway.

Comment: Server Fault is probably a bit different though. In this case they would be moving questions (with already accepted answers) from a production site to a beta EE site, which could still technically be closed. Better to just re-ask the questions here, and earn rep while you're at it!